# JSONDecodeError on PythonAnywhere

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

I'm trying to deploy my app on PythonAnywhere. Everything is running ok, but when I call a function, my app fails.

Exception Type:     JSONDecodeError
Exception Value:    Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

[Error Imgur image part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6A9M.jpg)

[Error Imgur image part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnVhT.jpg)

I have been reading another answers, but no one is working for me. The problem is this piece of code:

```
        parametros = {'location': lugar, 'API_KEY': api_code}
        url = 'http://servizos.meteogalicia.es/apiv3/findPlaces'

        # Enviamos la peticion
        peticion = requests.get(url, parametros)

        # Obtenemos la respuesta
        respuesta = json.loads(peticion.text)
```

---

UPDATE 1

The same error:

```
        parametros = {'location': lugar, 'API_KEY': api_code, 'format': 'application/json'}
        url = 'http://servizos.meteogalicia.es/apiv3/findPlaces'

        # Enviamos la peticion
        try:
            peticion = requests.get(url, parametros)
        except:
            peticion.raise_for_status()

        # Obtenemos la respuesta
        respuesta = json.loads(peticion.text)
```

And the JSON seems to be valid:

[JSON validation](https://ibb.co/fdr0i5)

Comment: Try `requests.json()` instead - let it figure out the encoding.

Comment: Exactly the same error @tdelaney

Comment: Ok, the problem seems to be this:

https://ibb.co/e5aki5

I don't know why support didn't tell me that when I tried to get support for the first time....

Comment: Interestng. The first time a second exception was raised while processing the first making it harder to spot.

Comment: Posting notes: we prefer images to be uploaded to imgur.com, preferably via the integrated uploader. This makes external image links more robust for the future. For pasteboards, we prefer these are not used at all, since the links die and leave a question that (sometimes) does not make sense without it. Would you be able to edit that into the question? I appreciate it is solved for you, but we like to keep Q&A in a good state for future readers here. Thanks!

Comment: You are absolutely right @halfer, my fault.

Tonight I will reproduce the error and upload the image.

Comment: Lovely, much appreciated. It is insufficient thanks, but once you have edited, ping me for upvote unicorn points!

Comment: Edited; much better this way. Thanks again @halfer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I received this support message, so the problem is solved:

> Ah! Sorry, I really should have spotted that first. Free users are restricted to accessing sites on a whitelist of websites with official documented APIs, and for some reason I thought the site was already on the whitelist.
>
> I'll add it now and let you know when it's active.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably here:

```
File "./consulta/views.py" in formulario
  32.             respuesta = json.loads(peticion.text)
```

It seems that `peticion.text` is not a valid JSON string.

Comment: Try to add `peticion.raise_for_status()` after `get` call in case, the response is an error response (you should anyway wrap the call in try - except block and handle errors).